# PLS-00357 sequence.nextval not allowed

Tags: triggers, oracle10g, sequence

I'm trying to create a trigger and am getting the error "[Error] PLS-00357: PLS-00357: Table, View Or Sequence reference 'table_data_seq.nextval' not allowed in this context"

I have read a lot of information on the error and cannot find the difference between the PL/SQL that people say works and mine. Below is my code for creating the trigger ( keeping it as basic as possible to get it working ):

```
create or replace trigger tr_tabData 
before insert on table_data
for each row
DECLARE
seq_value int;
begin
       select table_data_sq.nextval into seq_value from dual;
end;
```

Oracle version is 10.2.0.5

As requested here it the script for the sequence:

```
DROP SEQUENCE DATA_ADMIN.TABLE_DATA_SQ;

CREATE SEQUENCE DATA_ADMIN.TABLE_DATA_SQ
  START WITH 1000
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  CACHE 20
  NOORDER;
```

Comment: That error normally implies you are using a sequence in a PL/SQL context.  For example, `seq_value := table_data_sq.nextval;` would not work in 10g, but would work in 11g.  But your code is using the old-fashioned way of getting a sequence, I'm not sure why it's failing.  Did you perhaps paste the wrong version of the code?

Comment: That is the statement sitting in my toad for oracle sql editor screen. I try to run it and I get the error above.

Comment: What happens when you run it in SQL*Plus?  This code works fine for me on 11g or 12c, but unfortunately I don't have access to a 10g instance.

Comment: @user1567453 Please, show sequence DDL as well.

Comment: That may be the code in your Toad window, but if you've made multiple attempts at this it might still be trying to recompile an old version - at the point to do an insert. Does changing it to `create or replace trigger ...` change (or get rid of) the error?

Comment: @jonearles I tried the above code in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer and it worked in both cases. It seems that we've discovered a bug in Toad. Thanks for the help everyone. Also sorry for the late reply (had prod issues pop up)

Comment: You may want to post your solution and mark it as accepted.  It may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was a bug with the TOAD version and my Oracle database version. The same code in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible before 11g. You can use sequence_name.NEXTVAL in regular assignments from 11g not before that, and that by the following:

```
 select TABLE_DATA_SQ.NEXTVAL into :NEW.YourID from   dual;
```